# Ошибка в выборке селектора содержащим определенный текст

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors

Приветствую. Мне нужно сделать выборку по селекторам с определенным классом и содержащим текст: "Сортировать:". Но, не работает ни такая строка:

```
var sort1 = document.querySelectorAll('(".view-list .d_inline_middle"):contains("Сортировать:")');
```

ни такая:

```
var sort1 = document.querySelectorAll('.view-list .d_inline_middle:contains("Сортировать:")');
```

querySelectorAll с contains не работает? Если да, то чем заменить?

Answer (score 1):

Читаем [документацию](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

> `element = document.querySelector(selectors);` where
>
> `element` is an element object and `selectors` is a string containing one or
>   more `CSS selectors` separated by commas.

Дальше идем читаем про [CSS Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_Started/Selectors):

> A CSS pseudo-class is a keyword added to selectors that specifies a
>   special state of the element to be selected. [...]
>   List of pseudo-classes
>
> - :link
> - :visited
> - :active
> - :hover
> - :focus
> - :first-child
> - :last-child
> - :nth-child
> - :nth-last-child
> - :nth-of-type
> - :first-of-type
> - :last-of-type
> - :empty
> - :target
> - :checked
> - :enabled
> - :disabled

Как видим, псевдо-класса `:contains` не существует, поэтому придуманная вами строка-селектор не валидна.

Решения:

1. использовать jQuery, который понимает псевдо-селектор ':contains или использовать [jQuery.contains()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/). Это ровно тот случай, для которого jQuery и был придуман. Пример:

```js
var sort0 = $('.two:contains("Привет")')
    sort0.css('border', '1px solid red');
```

```html
<div class="one">Привет</div>
<div class="two">Привет</div>
<div class="two">Пока</div>
<div class="two">Привет</div>
<div class="one">Пока</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

2. Написать свою функцию, которая использует `document.querySelectorAll()` / `document.querySelector()`, а потом перебирает содержимое элементов в поисках нужной строки.

Comment: по п.1: использовать запись по такому принципу
`var sort0 = document.querySelectorAll('.view-list .d_inline_middle').contains("Сортировать:");` ?

Comment: Нет. Я поправил ответ, чтобы было понятнее и привел пример. Зря я contains упомянул, ведь можно просто использовать ваш оригинальный селектор из вопроса. В общем, см. поправленный ответ.

Comment: ок, но мне по итогам нужно работать с sort1 как с массивом, а не переменной... к примеру - вот как в этом случаем применить css правило к первому встречающемуся `div с классом one` со сложной html структурой, если html нет возможности редактировать..?
с помощью document.querySelectorAll() мне это удавалось, но также применялось к таким же классом, но с др. содержанием ("показать"), что мне не нужно..

Comment: решил через `$('.view-list .param-count').eq(1)` вопрос снят